# MS Access 2007 - Cycling through values in a list box to grab id's for a SQL statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

Lets say I have two tables, one for transactions, and another table who's primary key is the foreign key in the first table, and this relationship simply associates locations to transactions.

I have a form with a list box that shows all the potential locations, so that the user can open some dashboard forms that only pertain to a given location. So I know how to pass the data from the selection to the dashboard, however I would now like the user to have the capability to select multiple locations from the first list.

so if I use a SQL statement the WHERE clause is like

```
 .... WHERE LocationID = " & me.lstLocations.value & ";"
```

but how would I equate this type of method to selecting multiple choices? I am sure there is some type of loop that escapes me.

Thanks
Justin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE LocationID IN (" & listofvalues & ");"
```

The list can be obtained like so:

```
For Each itm In Me.ListBox.ItemsSelected
  listofvalues = listofvalues & "," & Me.ListBox.Column(0, itm)
Next

listofvalues = Mid(listofvalues,2)
```

This is for a numeric list, a list of strings needs quotes.

Comment: @Remou....hey will the first example only represent those selected like the second one does? thanks as always Remou!

Comment: @Remou....also if I use the second example, I am hiding the ID value from the list box with the column width set to zero....this really won't effect that though, right?

Comment: The width of the column is not important. There is only one example here, an SQL statement and how to get the IN list for that statement.