# How to pass multiple values to parameter in Access?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, parameters

## Background / Overall goal

- I have an excel spreadsheet, with a list of items that certain roles need to test out.

  - Roles have members
  - Roles can have member roles, which have their own users.
- I need to grab the total number of users who could test a given feature to grab names and count numbers for some metrics.
- I put the users, roles, and member roles into an Access DB for some quick querying
- Now, just trying to get the proper information out. I don't mind entering a list of roles and having it spit things back that way.
- I'd like to avoid adding all the test items for each role to the DB (there are a lot of them and this is supposed to be a reasonably quick task).

## DB Structure

```
                       +---------------+
    +------------+     |RolesUsers     |
    |Roles       |     |---------------|    +---------------+
    |+-----------|     |ID             |    |Users          |
 +-+|ID          |+---+|RoleID         |    |---------------|
 |  |RoleName    |     |UserID         |+--+|ID             |
 |  +------------+     +---------------+    |UserName       |
 |                                          +---------------+
 |
 |  +-----------------+
 |  |RolesMemberRoles |
 |  |-----------------|
 |  |ID               |
 +-+|RoleID           |
 +-+|MemberRoleID     |
    +-----------------+
```

## Goal

- Pass a list of roles to a query (either through a listed parameter or string list)
- Return a count of unique users who belong to any of those roles or any of their member roles
- Quick and dirty -- doesn't have to be fancy

## Current Access Query

- Returns users belonging to a role or its member roles for a given role entered via parameter

> ```
> PARAMETERS p_RoleName Text ( 255 );
> SELECT Roles.RoleName, Users.UserName
> FROM 
>
> (RolesUsers INNER JOIN Users ON RolesUsers.UserID = Users.ID) 
> INNER JOIN Roles ON RolesUsers.RoleID = Roles.ID
>
> Where RolesUsers.RoleID In (Select ID from Roles where Roles.RoleName = p_RoleName)
>
> UNION SELECT Roles.RoleName, Users.UserName
> FROM 
>
> (RolesUsers INNER JOIN Users ON RolesUsers.UserID = Users.ID) 
> INNER JOIN Roles ON RolesUsers.RoleID = Roles.ID
>
> Where RolesUsers.RoleID IN (
> SELECT RolesSubroles.SubRoleID FROM RolesSubroles INNER JOIN Roles ON RolesSubRoles.RoleID = Roles.ID 
> where Roles.RoleName = p_RoleName);
> ```

## Ideas So Far

- Found [an interesting post](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/passing-multiple-values-to-one-parameter/) on how to pass a string of text into a where clause using Instr(). Not sure how I could necessarily tweak that to my situation though.

Comment: Ha, +1 for taking the time to draw out that table structure... very nice.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy -- tables are courtesy of http://www.asciiflow.com/ -- I've found it to be very helpful for situations like these.

Comment: You know you can say `WHERE Field IN ("abc","def")` do you not?

Comment: Regarding your, link, do you mean more on the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909137/listbox-in-ms-access/3909178#3909178?

Comment: Remou, I'm referring to an Excel spreadsheet that has a list of items. Items apply to multiple roles, which have subroles and users for each. For each item, I'm attempting to enter a list of roles and get back all the users that could apply to that item. I added some background in my question.

Comment: Your tag list does not include Excel.

Comment: Thank you Remou, great point -- I updated the list. The way I saw it, Excel didn't matter too much since what I'm trying to accomplish is being done 100% in access with values I manually am obtaining from Excel.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still confused. Are you linking the Excel file? Where is the difficulty in obtaining the list?

Comment: The Excel file has a list of test items (~100), and ~30 columns of roles with X's in the box to show whether the test applies to those roles. Then on another sheet, users (and member roles which also have users) are listed for each role. So instead of trying to do an excel function, it sounded like a job for a database. I need to query for each specific test to go through all roles and member roles and pull out all distinct people that the test applies to.

Comment: So I moved the roles and members into a database -- I would like to pass it a list of roles (which I can list out from the excel spreadsheet manually) and have it spit back all the users so I don't have to hunt and peck through to count them and then eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Surely you can do this if you link the Excel sheet to the Access database?

Comment: Note that `Where RolesUsers.RoleID In (Select ID from Roles where Roles.RoleName = p_RoleName)` should be `Where Roles.RoleName = p_RoleName`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve Goal 1, you can use Remou's suggestion above to type a list of RoleNames into the `WHERE` clause with the following query. However, it might make more sense just to remove the 'WHERE' clause, run the query, and then paste into Excel for (Goal 3) "quick and dirty" filtering.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Roles_1.RoleName,
            Users.UserName
FROM   Users
   INNER JOIN ((Roles
                INNER JOIN (RolesMemberRoles
                            INNER JOIN Roles AS Roles_1
                              ON RolesMemberRoles.MemberRoleID = Roles_1.ID)
                  ON Roles.ID = RolesMemberRoles.RoleID)
               INNER JOIN RoleUsers
                 ON Roles.ID = RoleUsers.RoleID)
     ON Users.ID = RoleUsers.UserID
WHERE  Roles_1.RoleName In ( "Prez", "Veep", "Staffer" )
ORDER  BY Roles_1.RoleName,
      Users.UserName;
```

To return the count of users capable of fulfilling the various roles (Goal 2) you can run the following.

```
SELECT InheritedRoles.RoleName,
   Count(*) AS NumOfTestersAvailable
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Roles_1.RoleName,
                    Users.UserName
    FROM   Users
           INNER JOIN ((Roles
                        INNER JOIN (RolesMemberRoles
                                    INNER JOIN Roles AS Roles_1
                                      ON RolesMemberRoles.MemberRoleID =
                                   Roles_1.ID)
                          ON Roles.ID = RolesMemberRoles.RoleID)
                       INNER JOIN RoleUsers
                         ON Roles.ID = RoleUsers.RoleID)
             ON Users.ID = RoleUsers.UserID) AS InheritedRoles
GROUP  BY InheritedRoles.RoleName
ORDER BY InheritedRoles.RoleName;
```

The above SQL assumes that each Role contains itself as a Member in the table RoleMemberRoles. You should use `DISTINCT` because the data model doesn't prevent a single user from having multiple roles and thus appearing multiple times in each result set.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: In your Access project, query the spreadsheet data using Access SQL e.g. create `JOIN`s between Access tables and Excel data, possibly using lined tables.