# Access: Multi-value field

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to design a form where the user can search records to filter a report. The user must be able to select many values from a particular field (multivalued field).  I understand I can use a list box, but the field has a total of 3,000 records and cycling through is too much. I just want to know what other ways I can let the user insert multiple values?

I have these ideas, but maybe you guys have another better way:
Creating multiple combo boxes and keep them hidden until the user hits an “add” button, but this limits me to the amount of values I can have. If I have 10 hidden combo boxes I can only enter a total of 11 (10 hidden plus the original visible) values.
Is it possible to have a temporary data grid where the user just enters the values.

Then comes the problem of getting this into the SQL Record Source. I am thinking of the SQL IN clause.

Any help or ideas, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any sensible split of the data? Categories? A-C,D-E ? Because is there is, you could add a combobox that allows the user to select a limit or limits. IN is a good idea.

Comment: More on IN : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310904/ms-access-2007-cycling-through-values-in-a-list-box-to-grab-ids-for-a-sql-stat/3311022#3311022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should create Comboboxes where values from next combo are dynamically populated when value in previous Combo has been changed so that way you can create hierarchy of values to select.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar for a few different applications in slightly different ways.  Basically, I present the user with a table, allow them to right-click > filter (the same could be accomplished by providing a filter textbox for each corresponding field in the table you want to allow filtering on... in your case it sounds like you only need one).  The filter box allows them to use 'and' and 'or' along with the actual text of what they're looking for.  Then they click a button that opens the report and fills the report's filter field with whatever filter they had applied.

Of course, this assumes the user is familiar with the data they're filtering, and requires a bit of training, but for me it was a simpler alternative than displaying a list with a bajillion entries in it.  Your mileage of course may vary :)