# Using a VBA array in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to write some code that uses SQL to delete rows from several tables.

A user would type type numbers into a textbox that are separated by a comma which is used in the WHERE clause of a SQL DELETE statement.

I have managed to split the string into a variant array and now I want to insert it into my SQL statement.

How do I insert the variable into the SQL statement and have it run through every element of the array?

EDIT: A bit more digging has taught me about For Each Next statements. This is probably what im looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you build your query in VBA, then your list of numbers can be an IN statement:

```
 sSQL = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID In (" & MyList & ")"
```

Where MyList = "1,2,3,4" or such like.

As you can see, you do not need an array and a textbox would be more suitable than a combobox. If you wish to allow your users to select by say, a name, then a listbox is useful. You can iterate through the selected items in the listbox and build a string from IDs to be used in the Delete statement. ( [MS Access 2007 - Cycling through values in a list box to grab id's for a SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310904/ms-access-2007-cycling-through-values-in-a-list-box-to-grab-ids-for-a-sql-sta/3311022#3311022) )

You can then execute the sql against an instance of a database. For example:

```
 Dim db As Database

 Set db = CurrentDB
 db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

 MsgBox "You deleted " & db.RecordsAffected & " records."
```

Comment: Sorry I got my terminology mixed up and used comboxbox when I did actually mean textbox.I did not know about the where in statement and i will use that in the future. I have to do other things to these numbers which I need to use an array for so your answer isnt suitable in this case. I have managed to solve the problem myself. Ill mark as accept though because it is a very good answer and taught me something new.

Comment: It is very easy indeed to create an array from a list in VBA. `List = "1,2,3"; Ary = Split(List,",")`, but I doubt that you can use an array in an sql statement.

Comment: I used a for each next statement to do it.

Comment: That is the long way round. :)

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach

```
WHERE 
','+Array+',' like '%,'+col+',%'
```

It will consider all the numbers available in your Array

Answer (score 0):

You could make it simple and elaborate a string, something like

```
stringBuilder sb = StringBuilder("DELETE FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ");
foreach(string st in stringArray){
    sb.append("YOURFIELD='" + st + "'");
    //If it is not the last element, add an "OR"
    if (st != stringArray[stringArray.length -1]) sb.append(" OR ");
}

//Now, you have a string like
//DELETE FROM YOURTABLE WHERE YOURFIELD='hello' OR YOURFIELD='YES'

//... do something with the command
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will fail if you want to run SQL query on two (or multiple) columns using array values from two different arrays. .e.g

```
where col1=array1(i) and col2=array2(i)
```